# What is the purpose of the clamper circuits here?

Tags: mosfet-driver, diode-clamp, cell-balancing

I've looking at cell equalizing circuits, and just because it's expensive to drive them with isolated drivers I have come across this circuit which does the same thing with simple clamper circuits:

[image]

I have difficulties understanding what exactly the clamper circuits do here.

Comment: What part of the circuit are you calling a clamper?

Comment: diode and capacitor part

Comment: It's written right on the schematic.  It's a DC restore circuit so that the AC coupled gate drivers can control the FETs.